# Displaying parts of objects in an Actionscript list

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have an interesting situation where I have a listbox that displays an ArrayList of strings, but I want to be able to associate the strings displayed with some other data which I *don't* want to display.

One way I can do this is, of course, to create an associative array that keys on the strings displayed in the listbox. The only thing that bothers me is having to maintain two separate arrays in order to do this. The list could get somewhat large, and I don't want to have to eat up too much memory duplicating the strings I am displaying, and of course it could impact performance if I am always copying my display strings in separate arrays.

What I would like to do is have a single array of objects that include the string that I want to display in the listbox. I'd like to be able to display the string without displaying any of the other data in the object, and when I make a selection in the listbox my selection allows me to access the rest of the data in the object.

Is there any way to do this? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `DataProvider`:

```
var dataProvider:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
dataProvider.addItem({label:"test", data:{x:0,y:10,someOtherData:"misc"}});
dataProvider.addItem({label:"test 2", data:{x:30,y:120,someOtherData:"foo"}});
list_box.dataProvider = dataProvider;
...
trace(list_box.getItemAt(1).data.someOtherData); //foo
```

Note, you can instantiate (by passing an argument to the constructor) the `DataProvider` using a list, XML instance, or an array of data objects as the data source.